# Problems while returning several values in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I am returning several values in a function:

```
def count_chars(e):
    return len(e), 'bar'
```

like this:

```
for d in lst:
    newlst = []
    for x in d["data"]:
        newlst.extend([x, count_chars(x)])
        d["data"] = newlst
pprint(lst)
```

However, when I return the values the come inside a tuple:

```
{'data': ['YES', (9, 'bar')], 'info': 'AKP'}
```

How can I get rid of the tuple? for

```
{'data': ['YES', 9, 'bar'], 'info': 'AKP'}
```

Comment: What are you passing in `lst`?

Comment: a list of dicts @dataLeo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unpack the function result (which is a `tuple`) with the `*` operator:

```
newlst.extend([x, *count_chars(x)])
```

That syntax is only available in Python >= 3.5. Otherwise you can use simple concatenation:

```
newlst.extend([x] + list(count_chars(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks! for the help